# Regex and strings, how do I fix a ' in a string?

Tags: regex, string

In reference to this: [String issues. Format "First Last" to format "Last, First" with a twist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25966628/string-issues-format-first-last-to-format-last-first-with-a-twist)

I have the function working well for mos names.  However, I'm stuck on names with a ' in them, ie: O'Shane.  I loop though a dataset, pass the name to the function to fix it, then return the fixed name.  However, with the string having a ' in it, it messes up the SQL statement.

Here's the relevant code:

```
 strSql = ("update tbl set Name=" & "'" & strNewName & "'" & " where ID= " & "'" & ID & "'")

strNewName = NameFix(strName)

 Public Function NameFix(ByVal strOriginalName As String) As String
Dim regex As New Regex("(?:(?:mr\.|miss|mrs|ms|by)\s+)?(\S+).*(?<=\s)(\S+)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        Dim strNewName As String = regex.Replace(strOriginalName, "$2, $1")
        Return strNewName
```

how do i get past the ' in a name?

tia!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SQL parameters - do not put user-entered values in an SQL statement **ever**. This is a big security hole known as SQL injection.

While you could replace every `'` with `''` to escape the quote, it's still a bad practice. Using SQL parameters will let the server optimize and cache query plans for reuse with different parameters.

Your query would look like this:

```
UPDATE tbl SET Name = @newName WHERE ID = @id
```

Then you add the values to the [`SqlCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) collection if you use ADO.NET.

Comment: Thanks! Good suggestion. I'm not concerned with injection attacks for this because it doesn't take user input and it's not a web application. Plus, it's just for me, nobody else will be using it. So, I didn't even think of using parameters as a fix.

Comment: @JimB Get used to parameters and use them every time. After a while you won't even consider string concatenation as a possible option anymore. Even if you're not concerned about security, the query plan caching should be a good enough reason by itself.

Comment: Thanks again.  I'm going to use a PostgresQL db (just using an access db for testing right now), not sure if the paramter use or query caching would matter with postgresql - thoughts?

Comment: @JimB it matters in any decent DB

Answer (score 0):

The escape sequence for a `'` character is to add another `'` so do a replace on `'` with `''`